# Boot up problem after system update

Tags: boot, pi-4, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 which I recently updated with sudo apt-get upgrade,sudo apt-get update,sudo apt-get dist-upgrade.

After a reboot, it says autoboot.txt not found on a 'black screen of death' (which is attached). I have tried creating one with boot_partition=0 or 1 or 2 or 6 with no success.

I went back to an archive (on a different SD card) and Pi was working fine, but crashed again after system update and reboot.

Any suggestions?

[image: Crash report screen]

Comment: What OS? Are you using NOOBS?

Comment: It was a standard Buster installation with a new Pi4. A *possible* explanation for the fault would be that somehow the Pi4 is thinking it is a previous edition (i.e Pi3) as from what I am reading, autoboot.txt should never be used as bootbin(?) is on EEPROM i=on Pi4.

Comment: Normal procedure is update **followed by** upgrade and use `apt` not `apt-get`. *Raspberry Pi OS* does not use autoboot.txt and the boot screen should show 4 raspberries so we have NO WAY of knowing what you may have done (even if we could read the text in the poor image).

Comment: Thanks for this I have changed the order and using apt in my command file.

Comment: Thanks for this I have changed the order and using apt in my command file. The second point is valid but WHY has a Pi 4 changed to a one raspberry and used autoboot.txt which should be 'treated' by autoboot.bin in EEPROM. It would appear that the update code does not recognise a Pi4 correctly. And it has done on two working SD versions separated by 3 months of edits? I apologise for quality of screen shot, but I am sure I would have got complaints for a high res version! and most of the shot is academic anyway indicating a look for the .elf files on the SD card rather than than the EEPROM.

Comment: Can you please add all the information to the question that you have given in some comments? You can [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/115985/edit) the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the problem but not why it happened in the first place.

I generated a new system image on a new SD card. There was a substantial number of missing files on the faulty SD card root partition, in particular all .elf and kernel images.

I copied the root partition across.

I then needed to edit cmdline.txt and /etc/fstab to have the correct UUID for the SD card. Rebooted and all was fine.

On a subsequent update, it was found that Kodi was not updating correctly and aborting the update. Why this should corrupt the boot partition on two relatively independent cards during a system update is the major question. I fear someone else will experience what I have.

Thanks to everyone

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow your `boot` partition is corrupted/edited/removed/illegally(without proper permission) edited. And now it can not find the partition. This happens most of the time when we are trying to edit a file in boot partition with a windows OS that has virus in it. You have to take a backup of your `rootfs` and reinstall everything.

Comment: I agree with your suggested solution but why should two previously working versions fail on a system update? fsck reports no faults on SD card and there is plenty of partition space.

Comment: fsck will never find something like that. I have faced this at least three times. One time it was a Windows with malware. And another time it was a update fail.

Comment: Agreed, but just mentioned to indicate no file system corruption

Comment: @rallan I am not only talking about fs corruption. There is file permission corruption too